# How to get the value of a checkbox in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

> I'm having a hard time in getting the value of the checkbox in angular 2, I already use *(change)* just to get the value of the checkbox, actually it works but I'm having a hard time to validate my project, so if you could help me to find a good way to get the value of the checkbox, just please inform me.

---

> this is my html code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor= "let employee of employeeData" >
    <td>
      <div class="checkbox">                                                 
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{employee.id}}" (change)="EmployeeCheckbox(employee.id,employee.firstname,employee.lastname)">
        {{employee.firstname}} {{employee.lastname}}
     </label> 
     </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

> this is my .ts code

```
employeesList=[];
    EmployeeCheckbox(id:any,first:any,last:any){
    let name = first + " " + last;
    let len = this.employeesList.length;
    let add = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        if (id == this.employeesList[i].id){
            add = true;

            if (i > -1) {
                    this.employeesList.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    if(add==false){
        this.employeesList.push({id,name});
        }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: can you add the code which you tried

Comment: I already updated my post

Comment: Still a problem? I understand your real problem is the validation. Can you clarify your question? Also maybe a good aproach is by using Reactive Forms: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/basics-reactive-forms-in-angular